# Unity failing to use port after crash

Tags: c#, client-server, unity-game-engine, rpc

I am currently doing a project in unity. The project consists of a server and a client application. However when testing out the whole server client thing, sometimes the entire thing will just crash, because of mistakes made in code or whatever reason.

However, after the server crashes or fails to connect to somewhere once, i can force a shutdown on it (unity refuses to quit on it's own, so i kill the process) and then retry. The problem is that unity after restarting cannot get the server side up, it simply says that the port is already in use. And it will keep saying that until i reboot my PC.

I know that the server crash is my fault, but testing what causes the server to crash is just a mess if you have to reboot your PC after each small failed test you make. Are there any known reasons that a program would keep hogging ports like that? If the server crashes and i shut it down inside the editor, it simply tells me it ''succesfully disconnected'' but i think the problem is still the disconnecting part, it should be releasing the port but it is not. How do normal programs go about this process?

Thanks in advance,
Smiley

Comment: A workaround rather than a solution would be to dynamically change/increment the chosen port -- debug listening on port 10000, 10001, 10002, 10003, etc.  You should still fix the underlying problem of why the port is still open, but a technique like that might help speed things up.

Comment: It would if i could get it to tell the client on what port we are talking this run. Is there a way i can make the client go like: Search for a server on a port between X and Y? Without waiting for the connection try to time out every port it tries to connect on? (I would know some way in multithreading but i rather keep away from that inside unity, it is a downright horror genre in there)

Comment: My first thought was a user input dialog, but that's cumbersome if you don't already have one.  I know of no way other than repeated trials -- even nmap works that way.  Could you perhaps reduce the timeout?  If this isn't really easy, don't bother: it's not worth wasting time on as it distracts from fixing the actual problem.

Comment: I could look into that, and i will need a client side input at one point anyway, i could just build it and then abuse it for this debugging. So far so good. But i am still quite bothered by unity just crashing and not giving a whole lot of reason for it. I think ill just strip the entire thing and then start adding stuff back in until i find what is causing this annoying situation in the first place.